# Disable Back button in WizarDroid

Tags: android, wizard

I am using [WizarDroid](https://github.com/Nimrodda/WizarDroid) library, and creating a simple Wizard.

What I am trying to do is at the final step I want to disable **Back** button at the bottom. I have searched every where and the documentation is not helping me.

Here is my Basic Wizard code:

```
public class FormWizard extends BasicWizardLayout 
{
    public FormWizard() 
    {
        super();
    }

    @Override
    public WizardFlow onSetup() 
    {
        return new WizardFlow.Builder()
        /*
         * Mark this step as 'required', preventing the user from advancing to the
         * next step without selecting one option.
         */
        .addStep(Form1.class, true)
        .addStep(Form2.class, true)
        .addStep(Form3.class)
        .create();
    }

    @Override
    public void onWizardComplete()
    {
        super.onWizardComplete(); 

        // Terminate the wizard
        getActivity().finish(); 
    }
}
```

The Form1,Form2 and Form3 are simply extending **WizardStep** and showing some data to user.

In the documentation the **wizard.goNext();** method is defined but it is not available in my scenario.

I simply want to disable the user to go back after they reach at Form3 or final step.

Answer (score 0):

If you are talking about disabling the software/hardware (next to the home button and menu button) then you simply have to handle the onPress yourself. Example:

```
//FOR API 5-
@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Can't go back", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}

//FOR API 6+
@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) {
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Can't go back", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        return true;
    } else {
        return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);
    }
}
```